# Google ads API - REST API

Tags: google-ads-api, rest

Hope you all are doing well. I am new working with Google ads api. I have to retrieve information regarding keywords i.e how many people searched certain keywords , how many clicks and so on... so I have created a manager account on Google ads and under that I have created client account. In client account I have added keywords under keyword planner and I am getting all information mentioned above but I want to get it through REST API in python.

I have everything needed to access API:
(Developer token
login_customer_id
Client ID
Client Secret
refresh token) I have given this information in the .yaml file. and I assume login_customer_id is the manager account id.
Below is the code to access all the keywords information. here I have given the client_idfrom which I want to access keywords information.

import argparse
import sys
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException

def main(client, customer_id):
ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")

```
query = """
    SELECT
      campaign.id,
      campaign.name,
      ad_group.id,
      ad_group.name,
      ad_group_criterion.criterion_id,
      ad_group_criterion.keyword.text,
      ad_group_criterion.keyword.match_type,
      metrics.impressions,
      metrics.clicks,
      metrics.cost_micros
    FROM keyword_view WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_7_DAYS
    AND campaign.advertising_channel_type = 'SEARCH'
    AND ad_group.status = 'ENABLED'
    AND ad_group_criterion.status IN ('ENABLED', 'PAUSED')
    ORDER BY metrics.impressions DESC
    LIMIT 50"""

# Issues a search request using streaming.
search_request = client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest")
search_request.customer_id = customer_id
search_request.query = query
response = ga_service.search_stream(search_request)
for batch in response:
    for row in batch.results:
        campaign = row.campaign
        ad_group = row.ad_group
        criterion = row.ad_group_criterion
        metrics = row.metrics
        print(
            f'Keyword text "{criterion.keyword.text}" with '
            f'match type "{criterion.keyword.match_type.name}" '
            f"and ID {criterion.criterion_id} in "
            f'ad group "{ad_group.name}" '
            f'with ID "{ad_group.id}" '
            f'in campaign "{campaign.name}" '
            f"with ID {campaign.id} "
            f"had {metrics.impressions} impression(s), "
            f"{metrics.clicks} click(s), and "
            f"{metrics.cost_micros} cost (in micros) during "
            "the last 7 days."
        )
# [END get_keyword_stats]
```

if **name** == "**main**":

googleads_client=GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("C:\Users\AnoshpaBansari\PycharmProjects\GoogleAPI\src\creds\googleads.yaml")

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=("Retrieves a campaign's negative keywords.")
)
# The following argument(s) should be provided to run the example.
#parser.add_argument(
 #   "-c",
  #  "--customer_id",
   # type=str,
    #required=True,
    #help="The Google Ads customer ID.",
#)
#args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    main(googleads_client, "----------")
except GoogleAdsException as ex:
    print(
        f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status '
        f'"{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
    )
    for error in ex.failure.errors:
        print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
        if error.location:
            for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
    sys.exit(1)
```

but when I run the code I receive this error. I don't know what I am doing wrong.. Can anyone please help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6zO1.png)

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You must login in [Google Ads Manager accounts](https://ads.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/), go Tools & Settings > API Center and accept the API terms and conditions.